# Python code is working on windows but not on MAC

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    # Apply file type filter   
    if fname.endswith(file_type):

         # Open file for reading
        fo = open(search_path + fname)

        # Read the first line from the file
        line = fo.readline()

        # Initialize counter for line number
        line_no = 1

        # Loop until EOF
        while line != '' :
                # Search for string in line
                index = line.find(search_str)
                if ( index != -1) :
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")

                # Read next line
                line = fo.readline()  

                # Increment line counter
                line_no += 1
        # Close the files
        fo.close()
```

I'm Getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXXXXXX/Desktop/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/find_File.py", line 27, in <module>
    line = fo.readline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 117: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Once the character "–" ( using ISO-8859-15 encoding ) that looks like <==> was removed form the diff, RBT worked fine.
This seems to me like a bug in RBT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text from the file is either not encoded as UTF-8 or the file is corrupt. The most common encodings are [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) aka Latin-1 and [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) aka Latin-9. The Python documentation has a list of [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Since UTF-8 is not working, you should try opening the file with the other ones, for example with Latin-1 by doing `fo = open(search_path + fname, encoding='iso-8859-1')`.

You should also change the way you open & close the file and iterate over its lines, i.e.:

```
# Open file for reading
with open(search_path + fname, encoding='iso-8859-1') as fo:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(fo, 1):
        # Search for string in line
        index = line.find(search_str)
        if index != -1:
            print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 117: invalid start byte

This is telling you that the file contains data that can't be represented as text. It's not a problem with your code per se.

Try opening the file in a text or hex editor and finding the 117th character.